# Symfony2: How to go back to a page where the request of a form was send from

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a link: `mysite/productnumber_2.html`. On this Site I have a formular in a twig template, the action of this form leads to `.../createAssessment`.

In my controller I do things like save in a DB.

My question is, how can I go back to the url `mysite/productnumber_2.html`?

My function in teh controller looks like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route(path = "/createassessment", name="create_assessment", methods = "POST")
 * @param Request $request The Request object
 * @return RedirectResponse
 */
public function createAssessmentAction(Request $request) {
$form = $this->createForm(new AssessmentType());
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {

    $assessment = $form->getData();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($assessment);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect( ## WHAT DO I HAVE TO PUT HERE?? ## );
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could redirect for request referer:

```
return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
```

Or even better for defined route:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('your_route'));
```

where `your_route` is path to you `mysite/productnumber_2.html` page.

Comment: `return new RedirectResponse($referer)`

Comment: @Syjin from docs: `The redirect() method is simply a shortcut that creates a Response object that specializes in redirecting the user. It's equivalent to return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('homepage'))`. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting

Comment: The problem is, that there are many roues and they will be createt by users by adding a product over another form. So there will be no fix route that I can add to my routing information. Bute the "headers->get('referer')" works for me! THANK YOU!!!!!!!

Comment: @NHG --> Do you know how to set a Value when creating my form? I have this in my function in the controler: $form = $this->createForm(new AssessmentType());
 $form->setValue('asssessmentid', $id);

Comment: @Zwen2012 Not sure. Do you mean `setData()` for updates the form with default data? 
Btw. You should ask new question - maybe someone else will help you.

Comment: Allright, I will ask the question seperatly! THANK YOU!!

Comment: @NHG --> Do you know if its possible to send parameters with return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer')); ? Like return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer',array('foo'=>"bar")));

Comment: So, it's possible in case whe you redirect for route, like: `return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('your_route', array('foo' => 'bar')));`.

Comment: Mh, thats not good, there's no chance to define a route, because the routes are generated by users...so they are not fix...